How to use associatedtype from the generic as a type?
I have this sort of code:
protocol CoreTypes {
    associatedtype TypeA
    // ...more types and various operations between them
}

protocol Context<Types> {
    associatedtype Types: CoreTypes

    var valueA: Types.TypeA { get }
    func setValueA(_ b: Types.TypeA)
}

class Operation<Types: CoreTypes> {
    var context: any Context<Types>

    init(context: some Context<Types>) {
        self.context = context
    }

    func perform() {
        context.setValueA(context.valueA)
    }
}

However, context.setValueA(context.valueA) doesn't compile. The error is:

Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'Types.TypeA'

It's like Swift doesn't understand that these two definitions use the same type:
var valueA: Types.TypeA { get }
func setValueA(_ b: Types.TypeA)

I know that I could fix this specific issue by defining Context<TypeA>, but I need to use it indirectly, i.e. from Types.TypeA. Is there a way to make this work?

It also works fine if I convert Context to a class, i.e.:
class Context<Types: CoreTypes> {
    var valueA: Types.TypeA { preconditionFailure() }
    func setValueA(_ b: Types.TypeA) { preconditionFailure() }
} 

as that way I can drop any from var context: Context<Types>, but using these "fake abstract classes" makes things less compile time safe...
So is there a better way to use associatedtype from another type?

You can write generic helper function to open up the existential type (SE-0352):
func perform() {
    func helper<T: Context<Types>>(_ x: T) {
        x.setValueA(x.valueA)
    }
    helper(context)
}

That said, from my understanding of SE-0353, context.setValueA(context.valueA) should also be possible, since the associated type of Context is constrained to a concrete type.
context.setValueA(context.valueA) compiles if it were:
var valueA: Types { get }
func setValueA(_ b: Types)

So it is possible that the Swift team didn't think of this case when designing/implementing SE-0353.

Thanks! It's surprising, but this helper does work! That's a very neat trick to convert any to some.

Another alternative was to pass both types to Context protocol as generic arguments and constrain them that it's the same thing. It's not ideal (and not what I asked for originally), but it works well for certain situations in my case:
protocol Context<Types, TypeA> where TypeA == Types.TypeA {
    associatedtype Types: CoreTypes

    var valueA: Types.TypeA { get }
    func setValueA(_ b: Types.TypeA)
}

class Operation<Types: CoreTypes> {
    var context: any Context<Types, Types.TypeA>

    init(context: some Context<Types, Types.TypeA>) {
        self.context = context
    }

    func perform() {
        context.setValueA(context.valueA)
    }
}

